# Grouping categories on a bar chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, reportbuilder3.0, ssrs-expression

I am trying to group together names, and count the number of tickets each assignee is working on. Then I would like to graph this information onto a bar chart. Each ticket can be assigned to multiple assignee's.

I used the below expression, but I'm unable to get the desired output. The numbers on the chart do not add up correctly.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Jerry*",Count(Fields!issue_number.Value),
Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Chris*",Count(Fields!issue_number.Value),
Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*James*",Count(Fields!issue_number.Value),
Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Steve*",Count(Fields!issue_number.Value))
```

**Table**

```
Issue_Number   Assignees        
     1           Jerry          
     2           Chris          
     3         James, Jerry   
     4         Chris, Jerry         
     5         Chris, Jerry  
     6           Jerry         
     7           Steve      
     8           Steve
```

**Desired Output**

Bar Chart Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you aren't specifying a specific condition to count, you're basically just using the same count for each part of the switch expression.  You need to actually get the count of each, so you'll need an `IIF` in the second part of the `SWITCH`.  Try the following expression:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Jerry*", SUM(IIF(Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Jerry*", 1, 0)),
Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Chris*", SUM(IIF(Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Chris*", 1, 0)),
Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*James*", SUM(IIF(Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*James*", 1, 0)),
Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Steve*", SUM(IIF(Fields!assignees.Value LIKE "*Steve*", 1, 0)))
```